# Inserting a foreign key, on missing key, update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
   tbl1:  
   ============================
   ID     |      TOKEN(indexed)
   ============================
    1     |      2176
    2     |      2872
    3     |      2881
    4     |      1182

   tbl2:  
   =======================
   ID     |      TOKEN_REF
   =======================
    1     |      2
    2     |      3
    3     |      1
    4     |      1
```

in each iteration the server would receive a 'token', and would update `tbl1` if no token exists, in this example token `"5241"` would require an insert into `tbl1`.

I need to update `tbl2` where `tbl2.ID` is **AUTO_INCREMENT**ed whenever a token is received (existing or not).
If the token is a new one, first update `tbl1`, and only then update `tbl2` with the id of the new token.

I was thinking on the [INSERT ON EXIST UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), but I don't know how to combine it into a single command.

To summarize:
I need to [INSERT ON EXIST UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) `tbl1` in each iteration and `INSERT` the resulting `ID` into `tbl2` in a single command. is that possible?

ideas?

Comment: Do you need to keep these in separate tables? It would be much cleaner to have one table with `ID|TOKEN|TOKEN_REF` and you could use an insert with an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause to increase the ref counter.

Comment: alas, there are other tables that use the token reference ID as well

Comment: are triggers an option? then you could do an insert on `tbl1` ignoring if there's already an entry and create an entry in `tbl2` with `token_ref=0` with a trigger if needed and then always run the update. Might not be the most efficient but does what you're asking :)

Comment: MySQL can't insert into two tables using one single command, you should use trigger as @fejese mentioned or create stored procedure for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared an SQLFiddle of as per Ondřej's suggestion, which may be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab903/1/0).

In the schema I have proposed the following After Insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tbl1_ai AFTER INSERT ON tbl1
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO tbl2(TOKEN_REF)
  VALUES(new.ID);
```